# can not move location and create marker mapbox react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl

this code is o create a marker using the value introduced by the user, and make this marker fixed.
but I don't even can create the marker, nothing happen.

it's stick in the initial location after rendering. I taught maybe it was a lat and lng order but I try that and it's keep loading.
I try also to remove flyTo but nothing changed

```
  export default function Map() {
    
    const mapContainer = useRef(null);
    const [lng, setLng] = useState(-70.9);
    const [lat, setLat] = useState(42.35);
    const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(9);
  
    const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");
  
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: mapContainer.current,
        style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11",
         center: [lng, lat],
        zoom: zoom,
      });
      map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl(), "top-right");
      map.on("move", () => {
        setLng(map.getCenter().lng.toFixed(4));
        setLat(map.getCenter().lat.toFixed(4));
        setZoom(map.getZoom().toFixed(2));
      });
    }, []); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  
    function getCoordinates(placesContent) {
      const { center, place_name } = placesContent.features[0];
      return {
        coordinates: center.reverse(),
        name: place_name,
      };
    }
    const changeMapCenter = async () => {
      const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: mapContainer.current,
         style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11",
        center: [lng, lat],
        zoom: zoom,
      });
      return fetch(
        `${MAPBOX_PLACES_API}${searchValue}${REST_PLACES_URL}`,
        FETCH_HEADERS
      )
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((apiData) => {
          console.log("apidata=>", apiData);
          const { coordinates } = getCoordinates(apiData);
          console.log("coordinates=>", coordinates);
          map.flyTo(coordinates);
          new mapboxgl.Marker().setLngLat(coordinates).addTo(map);
        });
    };
    const handleChange = (event) => {
      setSearchValue(event.target.value);
    };
    return (
      <div className="mapBox">
        <div className="sidebar">
          Longitude: {lng} | Latitude: {lat} | Zoom: {zoom}
          <div>
            <label>create your spot collection</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="spotLocation"
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={searchValue}
            />
            <button onClick={changeMapCenter}>search and create </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="map-container" ref={mapContainer} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try saving the map in a state and use `setCenter`

```
 const [ customMap, setMap ] = useState({ lat: 0, lng: 0}) // set your own initial value

 useEffect(() => {
      const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: mapContainer.current,
        style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11",
         center: [lng, lat],
        zoom: zoom,
      });
      map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl(), "top-right");
      map.on("move", () => {
        setLng(map.getCenter().lng.toFixed(4));
        setLat(map.getCenter().lat.toFixed(4));
        setZoom(map.getZoom().toFixed(2));
      });
      setMap(map);
    }, []);


    const handleChange = (event) => {
      // i assume event.target.value contains the coordinates
      // example 929292, 2929292
      setSearchValue(event.target.value)
    };
    const onSubmit = () => {
         let coordinates = searchValue.split(',')
         customMap.setCenter({ lat: coordinates[0], lng: coordinates[1]});
    }
```

Comment: @SomeoneSepecial I do that and get an error:  Uncaught Error:` `LngLatLike` argument must be specified as a LngLat instance, an object {lng: <lng>, lat: <lat>}, an object {lon: <lng>, lat: <lat>}, or an array of [<lng>, <lat>]`, I have a question, seacrhValue I am still needing it, how can I change it idf I don't use setSearchValue?

Comment: you need to use `const [ customMap, setMap] = useState({ lng: 292929, lat: 9929292}) // initial value` then in handleChange, you need to update the objects with the lat and lng

Comment: i updated an answer with a very rough example of what you do, you can refine it yourself by e.g. Using 2 input fields for lng and lat, and update them accordingly.

Comment: it's not working, thanks anyway @SomeoneSpecial

Comment: it's working but now what happen is that I have to click twice to get the marker in the target. it's render in the same location before going to the destination. thanks

Comment: your code only shows how you setCenter. You need to add the add marker function in onSubmit

Comment: I post it here, with the knew cod. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67483022/map-render-in-the-same-location-before-moving-to-the-target-location-mapbox-reac