# map render in the same location before moving to the target location mapbox react hooks

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-hooks, mapbox, mapbox-gl

my map load in the same location before moving to the destination choosen by the user. I tried all the ways, I thing something wrong with the onChange, but I coul'd not find the answer.

What I want to achieve is having an input triggered by a button, that search location in the mapbox api and return coordinates, and have the location moved to the target.value

```
export default function Map() {
  
    const mapContainer = useRef(null);
    const [lng, setLng] = useState(1.43278);
    const [lat, setLat] = useState(38.90889);
    const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(9);
  
    const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: mapContainer.current,
       style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11",
        center: [lng, lat],
        zoom: zoom,
      });
      map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl(), "top-right");
      map.on("move", () => {
        setLng(map.getCenter().lng.toFixed(4));
        setLat(map.getCenter().lat.toFixed(4));
        setZoom(map.getZoom().toFixed(2));
      });
    }, []); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  
    const handleChange = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      setSearchValue(event.target.value);
    };
    
    const changeMapCenter = () => {
      const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: mapContainer.current,
        style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11",
        center: [lng, lat],
        zoom: zoom,
      });
  
      return fetch(
        `${MAPBOX_PLACES_API}${searchValue}${REST_PLACES_URL}`,
        FETCH_HEADERS
      )
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((apiData) => {
          console.log("apidata=>", apiData);
  
          const coordinates = apiData.features[0].center;
  
          console.log("coordinates=>", coordinates);
  
          setLng(coordinates[0]);
          setLat(coordinates[1]);
          new mapboxgl.Marker().setLngLat([lng, lat]).addTo(map);
        });
    };
  
    return (
      <div className="mapBox">
        <div className="sidebar">
          Longitude: {lng} | Latitude: {lat} | Zoom: {zoom}
          <div>
            <label>create your spot collection</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="spotLocation"
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={searchValue}
            />
            <button onClick={()=>changeMapCenter()}>search and create </button>
          </div>
        </div>
  
        <div className="map-container" ref={mapContainer} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch your coordinates first, then create the map

```
const changeMapCenter = async () => {

      const results = await fetch(`${MAPBOX_PLACES_API}${searchValue}${REST_PLACES_URL}`,FETCH_HEADERS).then(res => res.json())

     const coordinates = results.features[0].center
      setLng(coordinates[0]);
      setLat(coordinates[1]);

      const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: mapContainer.current,
        style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11",
        center: [coordinates[0], coordinates[1]], //do not use state lat and lng here and expect it to change, it doesn't.
        zoom: zoom,
      });
  //do not use the state lat and lng here because it's not ready yet since it's async. You need to use coordinates[0]and [1]
    };
```

reverse coordinates[0] and coordinates[1] if i got them wrong.

Comment: I want to thanks very very much, you are the best. hours of suffering solved @SomeoneSpecial

Comment: remember when u use `new mapboxgl`, you need to redeclare `new mapboxgl` whenever you change center, if not u use `setCenter`. using state like `lat` and `lng` and expect it to change, does not work.